# Why is the C# 5.0 await keyword listed as an operator rather than a modifier?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

The MSDN library [lists the `await` keyword as an operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528). That seems strange to me - I'd have thought it was a modifier, like [the `async` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Why is this an operator?

Comment: Because it changes the return type? From `Task` to the expected type, I mean.

Comment: `await` can only be used in the context of an async method invocation and not a method declaration, unlike `async`. Presumably it's an operator because it does something to the return value.

Comment: Actually, *Jon Galloway* asking this to the community sounds like a teacher testing his class =)

Comment: @AndreCalil Nope, I honestly don't know and am very curious.

Comment: @JonGalloway Just kidding. You got one good answer, I believe. I insist that it's an operator because it modifies the data type. I know that it does far more than that, but that's a conceptual behavior, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` is a modifier for a declaration. Similar to `public`.

`await` is an operation that consumes an asynchronous operator and does something with it. Similar to `return`.

`await` isn't modifying what is placed after it, but instead specifying how that operation is handled. In contrast `async` doesn't actually modify anything, it merely marks that a particular method is in the style of `async` (it is the eventual `await`'s that perform all of the changes to the methods structure from a syntatic standpoint).

Comment: "Does something" would be to transform the async task result into the expected type, I suppose. +1

Comment: @AndreCalil: It is also allows the compiler to transform the underlying function into multiple functions in order to support the appropriate continuation passing style if I am remembering correctly. Does something seemed easier to say than all that.

Comment: I see. But I believe that what most identifies it as an operator is the ability to change the data type, just like `>`, `==` and so on.

Comment: Did you mean to say it "consumes an asynchronous *method*"?

Comment: @AndreCalil: `??` is an example of an operator that doesn't change the data type.

Comment: @BoltClock: I was under the impression that `await` took in a `Task` or `Task<TResult>`, which would allow non-methods after it in corner cases. I can update my answer if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

A modifier applies to a declaration.  The private, static, out, ref, params, override keywords are examples of that.  And async.

An operator applies to an expression and transforms the expression result.  What you write on the right of await is called the "await expression".  It is thus a unitary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe that we all agree that it **is** an operator. I've been saying that the key concept to define it as an operator was that it *changes the result data type*, but that's not all true.

Let's look at the definition of an operator:

> C# provides a large set of operators, which are **symbols that specify
>   which operations to perform in an expression**

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So, as Guvante pointed out, we do have an *expression* denoted by `type identifier = await asyncMethod()` (mostly like it, you know). And `await` does perform an operation on this expression, indeed. It handles the waiting and the transformation from `TaskResult` to the expected type, and so on.

As I said, I agree with the other 2 answers (Guvante and Hans Passant), I just thought that this little concept could help too.

Regards